# Is this correct way of checking if file exists

Tags: android

I am trying to create a file on the internal storage. If the file exists then I will just append to it, otherwise I will create it and put header into it.

I did it by calling openFileInput and if exception is thrown then the file does not exists and I set it up. If no exception then I will open the file to append to it

Here is the code, Is it Okay? I feel there is so much redundnacy

```
try{
     openFileInput(filename);
     FileoutputStream  fos = OpenFileOutput(filename,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
     setupFile(filename);
}
```

Comment: NO. Exception handling is used when there is a exception that YOU the developer isn't sure if something that you cannot predict will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
public Boolean fileExists() {
   File myFile = new File(PATH);
   return myFile.exists();
}
```

Within the file constructor goes the full path to the file plus the file name that you are checking for.

This will return a Boolean value that you can then use for determining what to do in the case of true/false.

Comment: Do not use concatenation to build file paths. Please use the proper `File` constructor.

Comment: The problem is it is internal storage so I dont the path. Thats why I am sticking to the context.... methods

Comment: @CommonsWare could you quickly explain more why you shouldn't use concatenation? I use that for my Database check and haven't run into problems...?

Comment: @Snake you can use `context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()` to get a string that is the file path to the internal memory.

Comment: @TronicZomB: The only time it is safe to use concatenation of `A+B` to create a `String` representation of the path is if `A` and `B` are both constants, in which case it might not be worthwhile to do the concatenation. On Android, `A` tends to be variable `getFilesDir()`, `getExternalFilesDir()`, etc.). For those, you do not know at compile time whether those methods will return something with a trailing separator (`/`) or not. The `File` constructor handles that for you; concatenation does not.

Comment: @CommonsWare, it is not the concatenation I have problem with. It is the path of the internal storage that I dont know how to obtain (I have heard different phones could have different internal path)

Comment: @TronicZomB:Thank you . I totally forgot about this method :)

Comment: I didn't use concatination, I used new File(getFilesDir,filename). It is safer (I hope)

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like:

```
File file = new File(path);
if(file.exists()){
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: The problem is it is internal storage so I dont the path. Thats why I am sticking to the context.... methods

Comment: context.getFilesDir() + "/" + "GPSLog.txt";

Use that to check the existence of the file to create it and then append to.

Comment: Someone had the answer earlier . So I accepted theirs. Thank you though. I didn't use concatination, I used new File(getFilesDir,filename). It is safer (I hope)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
    try {    
       file = openFileInput(filename);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       // file does not exist
       return false;
    }
```

Comment: There is an expected point of failure when trying to open the file so you should test for the existence of the file before you try to open it. See my answer.

Comment: So in other words, yes, I think its simple and efficient enough.

Comment: My method is less code and better practise thus simpler and more efficient. So in other words, no.

Comment: True, but then you need to know the path, where as with this you can simply create it and not worry about where it is, and test for its existence with this.

Comment: I wasn't referring to your comment, I was composing that before yours appeared